# Delete a registry entry based on the value using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, registry

I need to delete a registry entry based on its value. For example, the key will reside in:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

The `DisplayName` key will contain `StackOverFlow`.

The names of these registry keys are GUID, therefore random, so I can't just search for them, the only way is the one above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'

gci $path |? {$_.GetValue('DisplayName') -match 'StackOverflow'} | del
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this but it doesn't do anything.. It doesn't actually throw up any errors either. I also added Remove-Item after the pipeline but that still didn't do anything

Comment: `del` is an alias for Remove-Item. If you take `| del` off the end, does it return any results?

Comment: @Mike, it's not necessary for you to have GetValue method. It's sufficient that $_ has it :-)